# Necesito ayuda para crear un expresión regular en javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

lo que quiero hacer es envolver los 'li' dentro de su elemento padre, en este caso dentro de la etiqueta 'ol'.

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular:

```
<div id="div">
  un parrafo...................

  1. item1
  2. item2
  ...
</div>

let div = document.getElementById('div');
let result = div.textContent.replace(/[0-9]+\.\s(.+)/gi, '<li>$1</li> ')
// lo que hace esta expresión regular es reemplazarme lo siguiente
/*
 1. item1
 2. item2
 3. item3

 por esto:

 <li>item1</li>
 <li>item2</li>
 <li>item3</li>
*/
```

Pero ahora necesito envolverlos dentro de la etiqueta 'ol' con otra expresion regular, pero no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi sugerencia es realizar el proceso en dos partes: Primero separar el contenido que se usará en la expresión regular, asignándolo a una variable, luego envolver el contenido en las etiquetas `<ol>` y por último reemplazar el contenido extraído en el primer paso por el de la variable que creamos.

Adicionalmente, asumiendo que necesitás un parser para markdown, podés usar una librería como [Showdown](http://showdownjs.com/)